# Pass C++ matrix into Python to use as Numpy array?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pybind11

I am doing some processing of matrices in C++ that I would like to pass to a Python program/function, which should accept data in the form of a Numpy array, and pass something back to the C++ program. I've looked through the documentation on [Numpy arrays in Pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html), but it isn't clear to me how I can create buffer protocol objects in C++ programs and pass them to Python programs, to be called in the C++ program itself. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: From my understanding pybind11 allows you to write Python modules in C++ so they can be used with Python. So with pybind11 you can create in C++ a function that processes a matrix and in then in your python code you call that function `from my_module import matrix_process` and do everything with Python, your module written C++ sort of being a backend and python a frontend.

Comment: @0x00 Pybind11 also allows to call an embedded Python interpreter from your C++ program, it encapsulates all the Python objects in neat C++ classes. It significantly simplifies the interop both ways.

Comment: What are you using in C++ to store arrays? You need to build a Python buffer object around it, and then call `np.asarray(buffer)` to create the NumPy array. Pybind11 comes with binding for Eigen matrices, so you could use that instead of rolling your own if you like.

Comment: It's a simple 1D array, so I use a vector, but I can expose the underlying array as well. Is there a guide on how to build such a buffer? The examples provided in the docs only seem to pertain to building C++ extensions.

Comment: Have you read this part of the python documentation? [Calling Python Functions from C](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#calling-python-functions-from-c)